# Jquery: Passing ID inside .append

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, selector, identity

Newbie here, got a question that hopefully is simple enough:

So I have this line of code;

```
            $("#r"+i+"c"+j).append($("<img>", {style:"display:block; margin: 0 auto;", src: imagefile, width: cellDimension + "px", height: cellDimension + "px"}));
```

and I need to pass " < img > " an ID so that I can interact with it in a separate function. Have tried the following:

```
            $("#"+ID+"<img>",
```

and

```
            $("#r"+i+"c"+j).append($("<img>", {style:"display:block; margin: 0 auto;", src: imagefile, width: cellDimension + "px", height: cellDimension + "px"}).attr('ID'));
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you interested in passing `"#r"+i+"c"+` value to the new image or do you want to give the image a new ID?

Comment: This line is part of a loop that adds images to a div. I need to interact with those images in a separate function so that I can move them around and thus I need a way to select the images separately. Is there any advantages to adding "#r"+i+"c"+j as an ID instead of any other name/number?

Comment: It all depends on what you wan to use the IDs for. If you want to be able to select any particular one image, then by all means use IDs. However, you have to keep in mind that no two elements show have the same ID; IDs should be unique. I would recommend using a css class, and a data attribute, if necessary. Can you provide a demo just so we can have a better picture of what you have described.

Comment: The reason I need an ID for all the image files is because they're checker-pieces on the board that I need to move around. I was thinking a draggable/drobbable function would do the trick and therefore I need to be able to select each image file (piece) separately

Comment: Here's a link to all the files, the one I work in is lab2-index.html. The rest is supplied by our teacher.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzjvrd9sQLIcUUg1T0dzNk5pbzg/view

There are some foreign words in the code(english is not my native language). Bildefil = imageFile, and also any comment text can be diregarded

Answer (score 2):

You could pass the `id` as a property of the object you pass when creating your image.

```
$("<img>", {
    style:"display:block; margin: 0 auto;",
    src: imagefile,
    width: cellDimension + "px",
    height: cellDimension + "px",
    id: ID_HERE } // ID here - either a string variable, or string literal like "imageId"
);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dmpd9a64/

In addition, you can pass a value using `attr`, like this:

```
$("<img>", {
    style:"display:block; margin: 0 auto;",
    src: imagefile,
    width: cellDimension + "px",
    height: cellDimension + "px"}
).attr('id', ID_HERE); // again, string variable or literal
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dmpd9a64/1/

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in passing the parent ID so that it can be part of the ID of the image, here is how to do it:

```
$("#r" + i + "c" + j).append( function() { 
    return $("<img>", {
        //any attributes you'd like to set, such as:
        class: 'new-image',
        'data-id': this.id,
        id: this.id + '-something' /* since IDs must be unique */ 
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can to this by:

```
    $("#r"+i+"c"+j).append($("<img id='"+yourID+"'>", {style:"display:block; margin: 0 auto;", src: imagefile, width: cellDimension + "px", height: cellDimension + "px"}));
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this is how I would do it:

```
$("#r" + i + "c" + j).append($("<img>", {
    style: "display:block; margin: 0 auto;",
    src: imagefile,
    width: cellDimension + "px",
    height: cellDimension + "px",
    id: id 
}));
```

Here's the working code: http://jsfiddle.net/silkster/jqqLmm46/